# CompressFilter conflicting with ExceptionHandlerFilter in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, action-filter

I am not getting my ExceptionHandling hit when I have the CompressFilter on the action and their is an error.  No response is returned on the request.  If I remove the Compress filter then it returns the error array just fine.  How can I skip the compress filter on an error, or have it hit second?

**Controller Action**

```
 [HttpPost, CompressAttribute]
 public virtual ActionResult Builder()
```

**Global.asax**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());
```

**CompressFilter**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class CompressAttribue : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
                var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted)) return;

                encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();
                var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

                if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
                {
                    response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                    response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                }
                else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
                {
                    response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                    response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: when is the compress added in relation to the error filter

Comment: Updated and added to the question

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282602/gzip-deflate-failure-when-an-exception-is-thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved it to the `OnActionExecuted` and it worked since it contains an Exception property.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

            if (filterContext.Exception == null)
            {
                var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
                if (!encodingsAccepted.IsBlank())
                {
                    encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();
                    var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

                    if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
                    {
                        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                        response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                    }
                    else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
                    {
                        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                        response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```